# Sklearn - Data Biased Towards False

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn classifiers, various ones but mostly focused around decision trees. I think I have an issue with bias. Here's what I'm working with,

Set of 25k training records (total data is about 500k available)
95% of actual data provided is false, because clients usually mark this data as false

25k training records includes 95% false and 5% true

When training and testing I'm getting accuracy between 85% and 94% depending on the features I use. Sometimes even as few as two features provides accuracy of 90% while 20 features (that I know are important) increase to 94%. I believe that this is not correct and my feeling is that there is some bias going on towards false because of the data I'm providing. Should I include more records in my training set towards "true", perhaps using 30k records, adding another set of 5k that are "true" values from our actual data?

Comment: This can happen even if the estimator labels all data as false, you can get 95% accuracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that all your test data is false which in that case by always picking false you can get a 95% of effectiveness.

You have a Class Imbalance Problem. This is typical in many real world scenarios. For example, HIV positive cases are rare that HIV negatives, cancer cells, or fraud transactions. You need to see what is the cost of False Negatives vs True Positives to be able to tune your algorithm to prevail precision over effectiveness etc.

A couple of things I would do:

1. Do a confusion matrix (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) this will help you also check how many false positive and true positives
2. Use cross validation to get better mix of train/test populations

Comment: Thanks again, this did help quite a bit. Now that I'm looking at this (and my brain seems to be working) accuracy is closer to 25%; which actually isn't far off from what I expected. I'll continue working on this.